# How to concat multiple jQuery files into one using Gulp?

Tags: gulp

I'm wanting to only load one JS file which uses jQuery code, but am confused about how to best do it. The thing I'm worried about is doing something sloppy like the below to solve the issue of loading all the scripts under `$(document).ready(function(){});`

```
gulp.task('compile-js', function() {
    gulp.src(['./js/initialization.js', './stuff.js'./js/end.js'])
        .pipe(concat('script.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/javascripts/'));
});
```

where `initialization.js` and `end.js` are for the wrapping of the  `document.ready` function (I know lol, hence asking)

Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Write a gulp file, lets call it 'jquery-noconflict.js'

```
var through = require('through2');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(){
  var stream = through.obj(function(file, enc, cb) {
    if (file.isStream()) {
      this.emit('error', new PluginError(PLUGIN_NAME, 'Streams are not supported!'));
      return cb();
    }

    if (file.isBuffer()) {
        var contents = file.contents.toString();
        file.contents = Buffer.concat([new Buffer('jQuery(document).ready(function(){'), file.contents, new Buffer('})')]);
    }

    cb(null, file);
  }, function(){

  })

  return stream;
};
```

You might need to 'npm install through2'

now in your gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var jquery = require('./jquery-noconflict');

gulp.task('compile-js', function(){
    gulp.src('./stuff.js')
        .pipe(concat('script.js'))
        .pipe(jquery())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/javascripts/'))
})
```